# Rails 5: Using a model function in a scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to use a model function within a scope and was wondering if something like this is possible?

```
class WeighIn < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :client

    scope :overweight, -> { where("current_weight >= ?", target_weight) }

    def target_weight
        client.target_weight
    end
end
```

When I call `WeighIn.overweight` I see the error:

```
undefined local variable or method `target_weight' for #<WeighIn::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fb31baa1fb0>
```

... which makes sense since the `client_id` is changing depending on the `weigh_in`.  Is there a different way to ask this question?

Comment: Can you explain, in English, what is it you're trying to do? Get all `Client`s that are overweight? Is `target_weight` a direct attribute of `Client`? It's not really clear.

Comment: yes, `target_weight` is an attribute of `client` and I want all `weigh_ins` that are overweight

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing you want to do something like `weigh_in.overweight` to get all `WeighIn` with weight greated than `weigh_in.target_weight`. You can't do that the way you want, since a scope is basically a Class method and `target_weight` is an instance method.

What you can do is to add an argument to the scope:

```
scope :overweight, ->(weight) { where("current_weight >= ?", weight) }
```

Then add an instance method

```
def overweight
  WeighIn.overweight(target_weight)
end
```

and now `weigh_in.overweight` returns what you want.

EDIT: if you want to get all overwight weigh_in related to its user the you have to join the tables like @Michelson's answer, something like:

```
scpoe :overweight, -> { joins(:clients).where('current_weight >= clients.target_weight') }
```

Comment: I accepted the answer but I'm still not able to call `WeighIn.overweight`.  Is there any change I can make so that that it pulls all weigh ins that are overweight with respect to their client's `target_weight` and not just one single `target_weight` across the board?

Comment: Check the edit, but @Michelson already suggested to do a join

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like this would work

> scope :overweight, -> { joins("clients").where("current_weight >= clients.current_weight") }